# How to inject track telemetry to a video as per camm-spec

Tags: python, ffmpeg, telemetry

I created a video using images and want to inject telemetry track data into it and as per https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/camm-spec

Can anyone tell me, how is it possible?

Comment: This post was tagged exiftool but while exiftool can extract such data from 55 different telemetry formats, it has no ability to embed such data.  I did post the above link in the exiftool forums so the author can take a look, though.